# I created a java class outside my Main Activity but I am unable to access it to use getter in my Main Activity

Tags: java, android

I am unable to get my `Message` class in which I set my getters and setters to use in Main Activity. My coding is showing error on `getContent()` in `onStart()` void. Below is the code of Main Activity:

```
package com.example.tejindersingh.chatapplication;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editMessage;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private RecyclerView mMessageList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMessageE);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages");
    mMessageList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messageRec);
    mMessageList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mMessageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    MainActivity mActivity= new MainActivity();


}

public void sendButtonClicked(View view){
    final String messageValue = editMessage.getText().toString().trim();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(messageValue)){
        final DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
        newPost.child("Content").setValue(messageValue);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Message,MessageViewHolder> FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder>(
            Message.class,
            R.layout.singlemessagelayout,
            MessageViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder, Message model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setContent(model.getContent()); //Problem here

        }
    };
    mMessageList.setAdapter(FBRA);
}

public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }


    public void setContent(String content){
        TextView message_content = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        message_content.setText(content);

    }
}

}
```

This shows the code for the external `Message` class in which I set getter and setter.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure your Message class is in the same package as MainActivity? I can't see any package declaration in Message, try placing it in same package with MainActivity, they both belong to same project after all.

Comment: @AnhaytAnanun Hi Ananun, can you please tell me how this thing can be done as I am new to android studio and java programming,PLEASE

Comment: Are your Message class in same directory as MainActivity? Check that, and if so, they are in same package. Also, include any error description you have, that will help people to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `populateViewHolder` method. the   `Message model` parameter, has `String content` which is null. In order to change that you need to use the `setContent` method.

Try to do this:

```
  @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder, Message model, int position) {

        model.setContent("Write Here Your Content"); //new line of code
        viewHolder.setContent(model.getContent()); 

    }
```

Comment: ,,@Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder, Message model, int position) {
                model.setContent("Content");                 //problem still there
                viewHolder.setContent(model.getContent());

            }

Comment: its the some problem of  model.getContent() is void?  or now its a different problem after you changed the code? please add a error description, that way we can see the specific problem